# Converting TIFF stack into BigTIFF stack - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, tiff, libtiff

I want to save a TIFF stack as a BigTIFF stack with matlab.

Wrote the following code:

```
function BigTIFF_converter (Stackname)

info = imfinfo(Stackname);
L=length(info);  

outputFileName = strcat(Stackname(1:length(Stackname)-4),'_BIG.tif'); 

for i=1:L
    frame  = imread(Stackname, 'Index', i); 
    bigtiff = Tiff(outputFileName,'w8');
end
```

However this code doesn't work for single images nor for stacks. The resulting file cannot be opened with the Fiji Bioformats plugin.

Also reading in the frames in Matlab using

```
A = imread('Stackname_BIG.tif')
```

causes Matlab to crash. What do I do wrong?

Thanks a lot for help!!